# Checking if test failed and giving console output accordingly

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, functional-programming, capybara

I am new to ruby and would like to add a step in my ruby/capybara test where 
"if Test A failed,
log this message in the console: "Microservice A is currently down."

Should this be done in the after hook or inside the test? Also, what would the commands be?

```
describe 'Test Description' do

  before (:each) do
    login   end

  after (:each) do
    logout
    if test fail do
      console.log ("Error: Microservice A currently is down")
    end   
  end

  it 'Check Page X Loads', :retry => 3, :retry_wait => 3 do
    page.should have_content 'Frisbee'
    navigate_to_menu 'Toys'
    page.has_content?("Frisbee")
    expect(page).to have_content('Buy Frisbee')   end

end
```

Thank you

Comment: Check if this class can be useful: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html

Answer (score 1):

The `after` hook receives the test that was run as a parameter so you can do

```
after do |example|
  if example.exception
    puts "Error: Microservice A currently is down"
  end
end
```

Comment: This answer helped me a lot,upvoted, thanks. Can you please let me know Is there any way to find out how much time a testcase executed, or how much time `it` block executed?

Comment: @Rajagopalan RSpec has built-in profiling -- https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/configuration/profile-examples -- If that's not enough you can always just use an `around` hook and do it manually.

Comment: Hi Thanks, This is not what I am asking, I am asking whether Rspec let us know how long a particular `it` has been executed?

Comment: @Rajagopalan That's exactly what profiling will tell you -- If that's not what you want you'll need to explain why it doesn't meet your needs - or do it manually with an around hook

Comment: I will tell you what my requirement is. Each and every it block is my each test case, after running each test case I need to know how much time test case has taken to complete, do you say it's can be done with the help of profiling ?

Comment: @Rajagopalan So you can either set `profile_examples` to a number larger than the number of tests you have, or (as mentioned) you can use an around example hook to do the timing yourself (save start time, run example, calculate total time), or you can use an after context or suite hook to access the timing RSpec has stored on each example in it's `execution_result` member.  This has got away from the OPs original question though, so if you need further details ask your own question.